# mathfield as a Enum java

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to build a Calculator for the school project. 
I want it to have a math field(R, Q, Z, N) field, in order to deal with different kind of numbers.
(the user has to choose the field before entering the numbers)
I created an enum of mathField

```
public enum mathField {
    R, Q;
}
```

and create a constructor of Calculator then gets `mathField` type.
but when I'm trying to create a new instance of  Calculator using:

```
Calculator calc = new Calculator(Q);
```

I get the message

> "Q cannot resolved to a variable".

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `mathField.Q` instead of just `Q` .

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Change it to `Calculator calc=new Calculator(mathField.Q);`

Comment: @Berger is correct, as well @IvoVidovic, `Q` in your case is something like name of variable, program doesnt know you want to use constant from enum, `marthField.Q` is correct approach, also notice in Java class name should start with capital letter

Answer (score 2):

If your Q calculator works in different ways to your R calculator, you should consider making Calculator an abstract class or interface and deriving your different types of calculator from it.

```
enum Mathfield { R, Q };

abstract class Calculator {
    static Calculator create(Mathfield type) {
        switch (type) {
            case R:
                return new RCalculator();
            case Q:
                return new QCalculator();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type " + type + " not supported.");
        }
    }

    abstract String display(double number);
    // some more methods here... some abstract, some with a definition common to all types
    // of calculator.
}

class RCalculator extends Calculator {
    String display(double number) {
        // display it normally
    }
}

class QCalculator extends Calculator {
    String display(double number) {
        // display it in hex. Or backwards. Or whatever strange behaviour QCalculator has
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = Calculator.create(Mathfield.R);
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not done a static import of a `MathField`* instance:

```
import static your.package.MathField.Q;
```

Otherwise, you must specify it in the format `MathField.Q` because it is unclear where we should get `Q` from. It could be `my.package.MathField.Q` or `your.package.MathField.Q`.

*I capitalised the enum name to follow the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If in same package :

pass the Enum value like `mathField.Q`

```
public class Calculator {

    public Calculator(mathField e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator c = new Calculator(mathField.Q);
    }
}
```